# Database Years Data as script

Tags: sql, database

I have a `Years` table in my SQL Server database.

I want to fill it with years between 1940 and 2014 in an easy way, without thousands of lines of code.

Is there an easier way to do this without spelling each year out?

Comment: do you have a text editor?

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow. We are glad to help you, but most of us appreciate you showing effort to make a readable, understandable question.

Comment: Maybe you're asking how to programmatically query on a date range?  If so, update your question for clarity or it will be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a TSQL script for that.

```
declare @year int
@year = 1910

while @year <= 2014
begin
    insert into years (year) values (@year)
    @year = @year + 1
end
```